# advance search text box in angular

Tags: sql-server, angular, search, asp.net-web-api, angular2-template

I work on an online search project 
I want to make a search textbox that works like: if I want to search about a book that Joe wrote it with title my book and publisher is tia. 
I type in the search: joe my book tia or tia jo book >
so I will get a result for it.
tia is from a table in SQL database 
joe is from a table in SQL database 
my book is from a table in SQL database

can somebody help me?

Comment: Will you accept my answer then? If my solution has helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily accomplish that if you add another column, that will contain concatenated data from other three columns, to your data table (in your database) and then make a search in that column.

```
writer title    publisher  search_column
joe    my book  tia        joe my book tia
```

Then, you can make SQL query to search by that column with `LIKE`
example with ExecuteReader.

```
var query = "select * from my_table where 1 = 1 " + filterQuery;
```

Create parameters:

```
public static SqlParameter AddSqlParameter(string parameterName, object value)
        {
            var p = new SqlParameter(parameterName, value);
            return p;
        }
List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
var filterQuery = "";
```

this will split your search input by spaces

```
string[] words = searchInput.Split(' ');
```

loop through your search phrases and add one parameter for each phrase found:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++) {
  sqlParameters.Add(AddSqlParameter("@p" + i.ToString(), words[i]));
    filterQuery = filterQuery  + " AND search_column LIKE " + "@p" + i.ToString();
}
```

add your search query and parameters to ExecuteReader:

```
public static List<T> ExecuteReader<T>(string commandText, List<SqlParameter> parameters) where T : new()
        {
            List<T> output = new List<T>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mySetting.ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        T t = new T();
                        for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            Type type = t.GetType();
                            PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(rdr.GetName(i));
                            if (prop != null)
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(t, rdr.GetValue(i) is DBNull ? null : rdr.GetValue(i), null);
                            }
                        }
                        output.Add(t);
                    }
                    return output;
                }
            }
        }
```

call your ExecuteReader like this:

```
var result  = ExecuteReader<myClass>(query, sqlParameters );
```

If you have further questions, just ask.

Comment: I'm happy that I have helped you. Can you accept my answer?